# SVN commit problems on Mac OSX Terminal

Tags: svn, macos

I had no problem checking out my project from googlecode in terminal. I tried to commit the changes but I get the following error message:

"...programming/softwaredefinedradio/out' is not under version control"

The problem is I don't have a file called out in my directory.

What would be causing this?

Comment: Can you show the command that you typed, and an "ls" of the files in the directory?

Comment: ...or maybe the results of running 'svn stat'?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by me wrongly using the -m option. my command line was something along he lines of 'svn commit -m took out ..." it thought that my message was a file I guess. changing it to "... -m "took out ..."" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a directory called "out" in your project directory, either as a result of building or running your code?